# Linux: can I create directories that don't exist while creating a new file?

Tags: linux, command-line

I can do:

```
mkdir messages
```

and then:

```
touch messages/hello.txt
```

Is there a command that will do both - create the directory if it doesn't exist, and then the empty file? Something like:

```
touch -p messages/hello.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not with anything in coreutils, but here's a bash function for that:

```
mktouch() {
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")"
  touch "$1"
}
```

Comment: Or just in one line `mktouch() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1"; }`